# generate a unique id (globally )not more than 20 characters long containing only digits and letters, no special characters.

Tags: c#

This is my code that I am using to generate an ID.
I am also stripping the result off any special characters like '=' and passing 14 as a parameter to this method.

Sorry about not being more specific before, what I want is to generate a unique id not more than 20 characters long containing only digits and letters, no special characters. This ID can be generated from any computer from anywhere. I can't use GUID, since it's more than 20 characters long. This ID will be used as a report number.

```
static long counter; //store and load the counter from persistent storage every time      the program loads or closes.
private static string CreateRandomString(int length)
    {

        length -= 12    ; //12 digits are the counter
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length");
        long count = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
        Byte[] randomBytes = new Byte[length * 3 / 4];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);

        byte[] buf = new byte[8];
        buf[0] = (byte)count;
        buf[1] = (byte)(count >> 8);
        buf[2] = (byte)(count >> 16);
        buf[3] = (byte)(count >> 24);
        buf[4] = (byte)(count >> 32);
        buf[5] = (byte)(count >> 40);
        buf[6] = (byte)(count >> 48);
        buf[7] = (byte)(count >> 56);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf) + Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);

    }
```

Comment: I'd say 1 in however many unique combinations there are.

Comment: You'd be wrong.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: BTW, `BitConverter.GetBytes(count)`

Comment: You'd also have to answer how many times you'll be generating... if you only generate one id, the probability of a dupe is zero :)

Comment: @SLaks - There's a reason I don't have an undergrad degree in mathematics :)

Comment: Yes. so the probability increases as you generate more and more of them..eventually...probability becomes 1

Comment: Thought about using a [guid](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/076c71fa-add4-4c6f-9b3c-f9f1cbea3de3/how-to-create-guid-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral)?

Comment: Why are you generating random IDs? What's wrong with sequential IDs; those won't be duplicated? Why must these IDs be 13-character strings?

Comment: @DourHighArch It should be less than 15 characters long, and it doesn't matter if it's random, it can be unique.

Comment: An alternate question is "How many could I generate before I have an x% chance of collision" where x is the probability you can tolerate.

Comment: @JohnGibb It can be generated any number of times

Comment: @user3015069 - if you say "any number of times" then the question can't really be answered.

Comment: @user3015069 `It should be less than 15 characters long, and it doesn't matter if it's random, it can be unique`. Then just use a simple sequence.

Comment: If you don't care about randomness or predictability, then use a GUID. That's what they're made for.

Comment: If your long counter is incrementing and is unique each time (as it looks to be at a glance) then you are going to be getting unique values until you overflow the long back to the beginning (not sure if it will overflow or throw an exception). And as others have said your probability is 0 for the first one you generate and will go up to a probability of 1 for a collision once you have used all possible values. The number of times is kind of important.

Comment: Sequential IDS are a great idea if you have the ability, but it means they can only be generated in one place... so if you have more than one server doing this, it's not practical.

Comment: I have edited my description right above the code, please provide some suggestions.

Comment: if you treat the 20 character id as a 20 digit base 36 number, you could maybe try creating a guid, treat that as a 122 digit base 2 number, and create a function to convert between the two. Some truncation would be required because the guid has about 10^36 possible values while the custom id has only 10^31, but I am guessing that would still be enough possible values to provide adequate uniqueness for your application.

Comment: You actually can do this, but before I vote to reopen you'll have to explain where that “not more than 20 character” requirement is coming from.

Comment: @DourHighArch - It's from the client. It's actually a form that's used by several agencies in a state (US). So everytime a new form is created, a unique number should be assigned to it as an ID.

Comment: You still haven't told us where the “20 character” requirement is coming from. Use a GUID.

Comment: @DourHighArch - I already mentioned in my above comment, it's one of the requirements put by the client. They do some exports from this form where they can't have more than 20 characters in the reportid.

Comment: You haven't explained what is wrong with your code sample. No re-open vote from me.

Answer (score 4):

Save yourself a lot of trouble by using a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

`var id = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: Hmmm...where have I heard that....

Answer (score 0):

1 in 13 to the 64th power. Assuming case sensitivity.

Comment: That's only for generating two of them.

Comment: The answer is completely dependent on how many are generated.

Comment: And also the fact that not all the combinations are actually possible if you look at how it is generated.

Comment: I am going entirely on the title here.

Comment: @Maess: Well the title doesn't give the whole lot. In particular you are assuming an even ditribution of randomness which is not the case here from the looks of things.

Comment: I have edited my description right above the code, please provide some suggestions.